# Error when passing parameter to form

Tags: python, django, django-forms

I'm trying to pass a parameter to a form, in this case is an object_id.
The form gets used only on the *change_view*, this code works:

My form:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.my_id = kwargs.pop('my_id', None)
        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

class Meta:
    model = MyModel
    fields = ('thing_to_show_a',)
```

My admin model:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, obj_id):
        self.form = MyForm
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, obj_id)
...
```

But if I try to pass the id as a parameter in the form:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def change_view(self, request, obj_id):
        self.form = MyForm(my_id=obj_id)
        return super(MyModelAdmin, self).change_view(request, obj_id)
...
```

I get:

```
'MyForm' object has no attribute '__name__'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `self.form = MyForm` you assign a class object to self.form.
In `self.form = MyForm(my_id=obj_id)` you instantiate an object of class MyForm and assign it to self.form.

Django expect to find a class in [self.form](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.form), not an instance.